# Python crashes using pyqt, setPixmap and QLabel

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I'm using this python code on a windows 7 64-bit machine, which simply displays a randomly generated black and white image. If I make the image larger than 511x511 pixels, my python 2.7 console crashes. It works fine on my Mac though. Any ideas?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np


class PixmapTest(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PixmapTest, self).__init__()

        imglayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        size = 512
        img_8bit = (256*np.random.random((size,size))).astype(np.uint8)     

        img = QtGui.QImage(img_8bit.repeat(4), size, size, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img)

        imglabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        imglabel.setPixmap(pixmap)

        imglayout.addWidget(imglabel)
        self.setLayout(imglayout)

        self.show()        

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = PixmapTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Seems to be a garbage-collection issue. The crash occurs with sizes >= 2048 for me on Linux. However, if I keep a reference to the `QImage`, there are no problems.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? How would you keep a reference to the QImage object?

Comment: Ok thanks this works too. I put a reference like `self.img=QImage(...)` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange, for me (Win7, 64-bit) the cut off size is closer to 300. I don't know why it behaves like this but in my case I can fix it by calling `processEvents` on the application, like this:

```
class PixmapTest(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super(PixmapTest, self).__init__()
        self.app = app
        imglayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        size = 333
        img_8bit = (256*np.random.random((size,size))).astype(np.uint8)     
        img = QtGui.QImage(img_8bit.repeat(4), size, size, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img)
        imglabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        imglabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        imglayout.addWidget(imglabel)
        self.setLayout(imglayout)
        self.show()        
        self.app.processEvents()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = PixmapTest(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. Can't vote you up, because I'm new.

Comment: This seems to remain a fix for crashes when calling 'setPixmap' multiple times in rapid succession.